# Twilio: How do I use speech recognition to figure out if one of the participants in conference is playing music?

Tags: twilio, call, twilio-api, conference

Given there are two people in a conference call, and knowing the callSid for  one of the participants, how do I parse their audio to know if they're playing music and in realtime, know when they stop?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no current way to get the live streaming audio of participants in a conference call so there is no way that you could apply any sound analysis to tell wether they are playing music or not.

Comment: Does Twilio plan to add some integration of this feature?

Comment: There have been public demos of real time speech to text processing on participants in a conference, however I think that is provided via the text rather than by giving access to the raw audio. I don't know any more than that.